# Merge fields of variadic tuple in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typing

I have a collection of objects with similar structure:

```js
const a = { x : true }
const b = { x : 5 }
const c = { x : `text` }
```

Every objects has an `x` field, but its type may be different.
All these objects are passed into a function `f` as a template tuple:

```js
function f<
    T extends { x : unknown[] }
>(
    ...t : [...{ [i in keyof T] : T[i] }]
) {
    // return t[random index].x 
}

f(a, b, c)
```

The function `f` has to return one of these `x` fields, but I can't figure out how to properly specify the return type for it.
For instance, in this particular case the type should be `true | 5 | "text"`.

I have tried to put `T[keyof T]["x"]` as a result but got an error `Type "x" cannot be used to index type 'T[keyof T]'.`
How this should be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  want the return type to be `true | 5 | "text"` you will have to use `as const` to preserve the narrowed type information.

```
const a = { x : true } as const
const b = { x : 5 } as const
const c = { x : `text` } as const
```

For the function `f`, you can use `T` to store a tuple of the types of the `x` properties.

```
function f<
    T extends any[]
>(...t : [...{ [I in keyof T] : { x: T[I] } }]): T[number] {
    return t[0]!.x 
}
```

The return type would be `T[number]`.

You now have the correct return type.

```
const result = f(a, b, c)
//    ^? const result: true | 5 | "text"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=41&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jAHjAXDKAnAVwFMYBfeCGUSKAWAChroYAjJVDbGAVjIqvDQGTWMHZpMOAAZQi6KFL5xKIhgwBmBMMCgBLcDHUAeBjDMwAKjDmywAE0pwwATwDaAXQYA%20ABQA6ANgcVwC-NFcASRhdMBgAayJnEHVLdy4JHAtItPJSdwBKTNcwAgBbFiI8NJRTczwiKAI8WKhXAAZ3AEI-TAZSNUZBWHqIAgAbWGR1HzgAGlZ54HyGAHoV8xgAPQB%20ARoYEfGoHHxiGAAfHguYACJZeRugA)

---

Here is a slightly refactored version.

```
function f<
    T extends { x: any }[]
>(...t: [...T]): T[number]["x"] {
    return t[0]!.x 
}
```

---

Also another version which also correctly handles object literals.

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};
function f<
    T extends { x: S }[], S extends Narrowable
>(...t: [...T]): T[number]["x"] {
    return t[0]!.x 
}

const result = f({ x : true }, { x : 5 }, { x : `text` })
```

Comment: As far as I can see the `const` is not strictly necessary here, but the `[number]` really helps.
Thanks!

Comment: without the `as const` the return type would be `boolean | number | string` instead of `true | 5 | "text"`

Comment: You have a point. Thanks!